# How can i know if my date is valid in java using simple Date Format?

Tags: java

*I am aware of the format using (yyyy-MM-dd) but the inputted date must be in yyyy/MM/dd and i am having trouble formatting it cause java wont read the format yyyy/MM/dd how to do this cause in model its in date format and i cannot set it when im returning string so return value must also be in date??*

**My request parameter from JSP**

```
String HireDate = request.getParameter("hireDate");
    emp.setDoh(DateUtil.StringToDate(HireDate));
```

**MY JQuery**

```
$( function() {
$( "#hireDate" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd" }).val();
});
```

**My Model**

```
private Date doh;
public Date getDoh() {
  return doh;
}

public void setDoh(Date doh) {
  this.doh = doh;
}
```

**DateUtil Class**

```
public static Date StringToDate(String date) {
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
  java.util.Date date1 = null;
  try {
    date1 = sdf.parse(date);
  } catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  Date sqlDate = new Date(date1.getTime());
  return sqlDate;
  }

  public static String DateToString(java.util.Date date) {
  String convertedDate = "";
  if(date != null){
  Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
  convertedDate = formatter.format(date);
  }
  return convertedDate;
  }
}
```

*I would like to make a static boolean function in another class which i will call to know if its a valid date whenever im using format yyyy/MM/dd in parsing it always returns the whole date including CST year etc,any suggestions??*

Comment: Allow me to suggest that in your model you use `LocalDate` from `java.time` rather than a string for the date of hire.

Comment: well,,there is valid reason behind that,cause i'm using that same model whenever i'm getting hire_date in oracle database and it does not read other format so i'm using date format in model..Its just that i would want to use it again in jsp instead of making a new model same date but string attribute

Comment: And since you mention `SimpleDateFormat` in your title: avoid that class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. The `Date` class is long outdated too. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: wait,,i posted wrong model,so sorry

Comment: there was another model of hire date from and hire date to which im using for searching,this is the model for the date im having trouble now,sorry

Comment: You should also prefer to pass a `LocalDate` rather than a string to your database.If using JDBC 4.2 or higher, use `PrepareStatement.setObject` and pass a `LocalDate` as the object to set. Your (modern) JPA implementation too will be happy to store a `LocalDate`.

Comment: in my code,i can already add data in my database im using to_date('Date String' , 'yyyy/MM/dd') its just that i need a validation kind of method to identify if its in valid format

Comment: and the reason why its date there cause i cant get the date in my database if the model is not in date format,in parameter and in data type,,so i really need help right now,is there a way for a date type be checked if its valid by not converting it to string??

Comment: I didn’t get that. No matter if a `Date` or a `LocalDate` it is always valid. You may perform a range check and discard dates that are unreasonably far in the past or the future, of course.

Comment: specifically i would like to make a boolean checker to check if its valid format like
if(dateUtilityClass.DateChecker(emp.getDate)==true){} then the checker would check if the Date is in yyyy/MM/dd format,,other than that it returns false

Comment: Neither a `Date` nor a `LocalDate` has a format. Formats only exist in strings.

Comment: i already have a string converter which converts it to string if i input 2018/06/07 in jsp i can make it 2018/06/07 again in string,im having trouble if its not in yyyy/MM/dd format in input,how can i handle it??

Comment: by the way i am really grateful for you having to give some time to a novice like me,greatly appreciated,, ultimately how can i return false or something if its not in that format in string,,

Comment: this is my converter of date to stringpublic static String DateToString(java.util.Date date) {
    String convertedDate = "";
    if(date != null){
      Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
      convertedDate = formatter.format(date);
    }
    return convertedDate;
  }

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Supplementary information for your question is very welcome. Please post it in the question using [the edit link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50942981/edit), not in comments. It’s still more important when posting code since unformatted code is unreadable.

Comment: Wonder if this is helpful for you? [Link: Date validation in JSP](https://www.roseindia.net/mysql/datevalidation.shtml). Search for more.

Comment: the thing is the instruction was must be handle it in backend and all requested attributes must first be validated before calling the class of querying in database if errorList > 0 it will be returned as request attribute and must be displayed,so,,,no